# Let $K'<K<G$ be a chain of groups s.t. $K\subset N_G(K')$. Is that true that $N_G(K)=N_G(K')$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $K'<K<G$ be a chain of groups s.t. $K'$ is a normal subgroup of $K$. Is that true that $N_G(K)=N_G(K')$? Obviously it is true that $N_G(K)\subset N_G(K')$, but is the inverse true? If this is not true, can I guarantee that they have same topological dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example the Klein four subgroup $K$ of $S_4$ is abelian and has a subgroup $K'$ of order 2. But the normalizer of $K$ is the whole $S_4$ while the normalizer of $K'$ is smaller.

Comment: And is that true that $N(K')<N(K)$ in the general situation? This would also be very helpful to what I'm trying to do. @JCAA

Comment: @AndreGomes Not necessarily. Let's recycle JCAA's example of $G=S_4$. If we select $K'$ to be that copy of Klein four, and $K$ any of the Sylow $2$-subgroups (all isomorphic to $D_4$, the dihedral group of symmetries of a square), then $N(K')=G$ but $N(K)=K$.